# Hive syntax: purpose of curly braces and dollar sign

Tags: syntax, hive

I'm reading over some Hive scripts from another team in my company and having trouble understanding a specific part of it. The part in question is:`where dt='${product_dt}'`, which can be found on on the third line from the bottom of the code chunk below.

I've never seen this syntax before nor am I able to find anything via Google search (probably because I don't know the correct search terms to use). Any insight into what that `where` row filter step is doing would be appreciated.

```
set hive.security.authorization.enabled=false;
add jar /opt/mobiletl/prod_workflow_dir/lib/hiveudf_hash.jar;
create temporary function hash_string as 'HashString';

drop table 00_truthset_product_email_uid_pid;
create table 00_truthset_product_email_uid_pid as
select distinct email,        
       concat_ws('|', hash_string(lower(email), "SHA-1"),
                      hash_string(lower(email), "MD5"),
                      hash_string(upper(email), "SHA-1"),
                      hash_string(upper(email), "MD5")) as hashed_email,
       uid, address_id, confidencescore
from product.prod_vintages
where dt='${product_dt}'
      and email is not null and email != ''
      and address_id is not null and address_id != '';
```

I tried `set product_dt = 2014-12;`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
hive> SELECT dt FROM enabilink.prod_vintages GROUP BY dt LIMIT 10;
. . .
dt
2014-12
2015-01
2015-02
2015-03
2015-05
2015-07
2015-10
2016-01
2016-02
2016-03

hive> set product_dt = 2014-12;

hive> SELECT email FROM product.prod_vintages WHERE dt='${product_dt}';
. . .
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 570 msec
OK
email
Time taken: 25.801 seconds
```

Comment: `${product_dt}` is the variable used in the scripting .You can use ! echo ${product_dt} to print its value. Try using TO_DATE('date') for comparison.

Comment: @AshishSingh okay, I do `show tables` and see a table: `product_20161029`. I try: `set prod_dt=20161029` then `describe product_${prod_dt}` but get nothing. I try `! echo ${prod_dt}` and get `${prod_dt}`.

Comment: try using `dt= (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(${product_dt},'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM'))` for comparison

Comment: my question is actually how the code above works, not how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

those are variables set in Hive. if you have set the variables before the query (in the same session), Hive will replace it with the specified value

for example

```
set product_dt=03-11-2012
```

Edit
Make sure that you are removing the spaces in your dt field (use trim UDF). Also, set the variable without spaces.

Comment: I tried that (shown above in the updated post), but the query results turn up empty despite the fact there are certainly rows meeting the `product_dt` requirement. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you try set product_dt=2014-12; I am not sure if Hive remove the space in the beggining or apply trim version in both sides also, it should work :p

Comment: Didn't work. I tried with many permutations, including one without spaces before or after.

Comment: SELECT email, '${product_dt}'  FROM product.prod_vintages WHERE dt='2014-12' limit 2.  Run it and let us know the result. Remember that you have tu run the set command in the same hive session....